# 'to date' under experience for Careers is not aligned

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

The **Time frame** section under **Experience** has a misaligned field for the "to year":

[image]

When the *Display options* are expanded, the field becomes properly aligned:

[image]

I think the field should be properly aligned regardless of the *Display options* being expanded.

I'm using Chrome 34.0.1847.137 m on Windows 7.

Comment: [me too](http://i.stack.imgur.com/4eZRZ.png) (Chrome: Version 36.0.1985.18 dev-m)

Comment: Yup. Confirmed. I'll have someone look into it.

Answer (score 1):

Neither of the screenshots in the question are aligned properly, regardless of the checkbox. Anyway, somebody has clearly fixed this at some point, because it's working now:

[image: Screenshot]